# How to script initializing the MediaWiki database when LocalSettings.php already exists?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm non-interactively setting up MediaWiki sites with containers, backed by a MariaDB database. All site specifics must be defined as variables in a configuration file.

One step in the setup is to initialize the database.

The only supported way I can find of doing that is by calling `maintenance/install.php`, which (at least in version 1.35) refuses to run when `LocalSettings.php` exists.  It exists - it is installed when the container image is built. The database can't be installed at that time.

A workaround is to temporarily move the file away when calling `install.php`, but that is ugly - it keeps us from making the configuration read-only.

Is there a supported alternative way to script installing the database that is stable across MediaWiki releases?

Comment: Is there anything valuable in `LocalSettings.php` that cannot be passed as parametres to `maintenance/install.php` as described in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Install.php, so that you can remove `LocalSettings.php` from your container altogether? Is there is, why don't you append it after running `maintenance/install.php`?

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of specific settings in our `LocalSettings.php`, but of course I can rewrite or replace `LocalSettings.php` after generating it. The only real objection against this is that it prevents me from making it read-only at runtime. I can get around that by remounting it read-only at startup time. Those are ugly hacks around a problem that feels rather accidental and that I think more people will run into; if there is an easier or "officially" sanctioned way around it that I just failed to find, I'd prefer to use that. Hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to discard the `LocalSettings.php` generated by `maintenance/install.php` because you already have your own complete `LocalSettings.php`, you can try to pass `--confpath="/tmp"` to `maintenance/install.php`.

Comment: This is a clean way out of this, thanks!